# Jsoup and setText not working in android

Tags: java, android, textview, jsoup, settext

Basically when I execute my app it either crashes, or does not display any text or anything.
I am using fragments and viewPager in my main activity but the class that is causing the problems is this one:

```
public class DailyWord extends Fragment {

Document doc;
String data;
TextView t;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    View mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_daily_word, container, false);

    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.urbandictionary.com/").get();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Element Worddata = doc.getElementsByClass("word").first();
    Element Worddata2 = Worddata.select("a[href]").first();
    String wordName = Worddata2.text();

    Element definition = doc.getElementsByClass("description").first();
    String define = definition.text();

    Element example = doc.getElementsByClass("example").first();
    String context = example.text();

    data = ("Word:\n" + wordName + "\n" + "Definition\n" + define + "\n" + "Context:\n" + context);

    t = (TextView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    t.setText(data);
        return mainView;
    }
}
```

Comment: post stack trace. realize it's an NetworkOnMainThreadException. close the question as duplicate to 1000 others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: Do it like this download answer from this link couldnt answer it for you here becos thread is closed..
http://wl.filegenie.com/~ikp4success/AnswerJsoup.txt

Comment: Please first try to search for already given answers on the related problem.If you don't find then put your question

Answer (score 0):

The below should be in a `thread` or `asynctask`

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.urbandictionary.com/").get();
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this within a fragment using viewPager? I'm having difficulties getting it to work.

Comment: @user1825241 you can use a thread or asynctask that is not a problem